# Selenium error "Timed out receiving message from renderer: 300.000"

Tags: python, selenium

```py
for i in range(100000000):

    #Finding current date and time
    now = datetime.now()
    current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    
    driver.get(thread)
    try:
        reply_box = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "message"))).send_keys("random test string")
    finally: 
        try:   
            post_reply = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "quick_reply_submit"))).click()    
        finally:
            print(MAGENTA + f"[{current_time}] Autobump #" + str(i + 1))
    time.sleep(1860)
```

My code works perfectly fine for around 10-15 iterations of the loop. After that, I randomly get the error

```
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 300.000
```

I've been looking all over the internet and haven't seen anyone else with this problem.

Comment: Most likely, you are getting an OOM or crash. How/Where do you execute the tests? Docker/Normal machine. Give some context information

Comment: I'm running this script on linux (home machine, not a server).

Answer (score 0):

The default page load timeout for Selenium is 300 seconds, and it seems you are running over that. It is very simple to change however, in your case increasing it, eg

```
driver.set_page_load_timeout(30000)
```

... or whatever you desire.